# A Linux editor to publish to Wordpress.com and Medium.com?

Tags: gratis, linux, text-editor, wordpress

I am looking for an Linux editor that can export (publish) writing content to Wordpress.com and Medium.com.

**Requirements:**

- Offline access
- Export to a blog hosted on Wordpress.com
- Export to a user profile (or preferably publication) on Medium.com
- Should run under Ubuntu
- Free of charge for personal use
- Open-source would be nice. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy! I keep forgetting about adding license and costs to my questions. I updated my question. What do you mean by subscription?

Comment: No prob – I'll always remind you #D [Subscription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscription): usually monthly/yearly fees.

Comment: What is ok here is SublimeText or CudaText plugin. I think if special editor exists, it will be worse than Cuda/Sublime.

Comment: @RProgram could you provide the links to the plugins? I couldn't find them. Thankfully, Robert.

Comment: I meaned that it is possible to make plugin for ST or Cuda, in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Emacs** is free, exists in every Linux disto, and has many installable *mode*s.  *Wordpress.com* export can be had with **[org2blog](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog)**.  *Medium.com* has **[org-sendto-medium](https://github.com/celadevra/org-medium)**, it's incomplete but seems to be under active development.